# Supply Chain Data of S&P 500 firms from Refinitiv Eikon

Tags: reuters

I would like to retrieve the list of S&P 500 firms' first and second-tier suppliers from Refinitiv Eikon using R.
I found one link that uses python for the first-tier data - https://community.developers.refinitiv.com/questions/93793/how-can-i-get-supply-chain-data-of-a-company-list.html

But unable to find info to retrieve supply chain data using R.

Kindly suggest if it's possible to fetch the second-tier details using R. Thanks.